# What is the opposite of the word 'optimum' for this context?

Tags: negation, antonyms

> The use of the **optimum** formula of x compounds is relatively small.

What is the opposite of the word *optimum*? Is it *non-optimum*? Could *inefficient* be a choice?

Comment: *Optimum* is generally equivalent to "best" or "best fit", but not necessarily "most efficient" - there's other ways of being the best (e.g. "optimum strength").  You would need to say *optimally efficient* for *inefficient* to really be the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by `opposite`:

1. Do you mean exact opposite, as `the hottest one` -- `the coldest one`?
2. Or do you mean just negation, like `the hottest one` -- `not the hottest one`?

## For exact opposite

I can't find antonym for the *adjective* `optimum`/`optimal` here.
Although antonym for the *noun* `optimum` is the *noun* `pessimum`, the word `pessimum` neither can be used as adjective, nor has correspondent adjective in English (and you certainly need an adjective here).

## For negation

The synonym for `non-optimal` is `suboptimal`.

> The use of the optimum formula of x compounds is relatively small.
>   On the contrary, **suboptimal** formulas/**suboptimal** formulae are widely used.

## Post scriptum

I recommend you changing the word `optimum` to `optimal` here, as you certainly need an adjective (although the word `optimum` can be used as adjective too, most people prefer to interpret it as noun). And together with some other changes:

> The use of the *optimal* formula *for* x compounds is relatively *rare*.
>   On the contrary, suboptimal formulas/formulae for x compounds are widely used.

(If I understood your original sentence correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your sample sentence. I know because I have no idea what it means.

Apart from that, I prefer "optimal," which is a natural adjective, to "optimum," which is not.

That said, there is no *exact* antonym for "optimal." But, since it means "the best possible under the circumstances," you might as well make do with "worst possible," "least efficient," or simply "horrid."

Answer (score 0):

From the Latin, pessimum, but that word didn't actually make it into English. Instead there's optimism and pessimism, but those are entirely different.

Because the word didn't cross languages with its native opposite, though, it doesn't have a clear one in English. Ricky has some decent ones.

Answer (score 0):

'optimum' is not a native English word. 'optimal' would be one. As such, its antonym will be 'non-optimal'(used frequently in mathematics).

'optimum' is an example of mixed English, which is usually spoken by non-native speakers. I, being an Indian, have seen examples of this among locals.